# Candidate function not viable - can C++ not deduce what my template arguments are?

Tags: c++, c++20

Basically I wanted `operator+` to work like append and `operator-` to be the inverse, a method that truncates the template arguments in the subtrahend (left hand side object) by the template arguments in the minuend (right hand side object.) It should only be available when all of the template arguments of the right are trailing in the arguments of the left. Here's tag.hpp:

```
#ifndef TAG_HPP                                                                                                                                                       
#define TAG_HPP                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                      
#include "utility.hpp"                                                                                                                                                
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                      
namespace X {                                                                                                                                                         
template<class... B> struct Tag {
    constexpr Tag(void) = default;
    constexpr Tag(Tag const&) = default;
    constexpr Tag(Tag &&) = default;
    virtual ~Tag(void) = default;
};
//template<> struct Tag<> {};
//template<class B, class... C> struct Tag<B, C...> {};
 
template<class... B, class... C>
constexpr Tag<B..., C...> operator+(Tag<B...> const&, Tag<C...> const&)
    noexcept { return {}; }
template<class... B>
constexpr Tag<B...> operator+(Tag<B...> const& b, Tag<> const&) noexcept { return {}; }
template<class... B, class C, class... D>
constexpr Dt(auto) operator+(Tag<B...> const&, Tag<C, D...> const&) noexcept
    { return Tag<B..., C, D...>{}; }
template<class... B>
constexpr Tag<B...> operator|(Tag<B...> const& b, Tag<> const&) noexcept { return {}; }
template<class... B, class C, class... D>
constexpr Dt(auto) operator|(Tag<B...> const&, Tag<C, D...> const&) noexcept {
    if constexpr(Or_v<Same<B,C>...>)
            return Tag<B...>{} | Tag<D...>{};
    else return Tag<B..., C>{} | Tag<D...>{};
}
template<class... B>
constexpr Tag<> operator&(Tag<B...> const&, Tag<> const& c)
    noexcept { return {}; }
template<class... B, class C, class... D>
constexpr Dt(auto) operator&(Tag<B...> const& b, Tag<C, D...> const&) noexcept {
    if constexpr(Or_v<Same<B,C>...>)
            return Tag<C>{} | (b & Tag<D...>{});
    else return Tag<B...>{} & Tag<D...>{};
}
template<class... B>
constexpr Tag<B...> operator-(Tag<B...> const&, Tag<> const&) noexcept
    { return {}; }
//template<class... A, class B, class C>
//constexpr Dt(auto) operator-(Tag<A..., B> const&, Tag<B> const&) noexcept
    //{ return Tag<A...> {}; }
template<class... B, class... C, class... D>
constexpr Dt(auto) operator-(Tag<B..., C...> const&, Tag<C..., D...> const&) noexcept {
    return Tag<B...>{} - Tag<D...>{};
}




template<class OS> requires std::derived_from<OS, std::ostream>
OS& operator<<(OS &os, Tag<> const&) noexcept
    { return os << "{}", os; }
template<class OS, class A, class... B>
    requires std::derived_from<OS, std::ostream>
OS& operator<<(OS &os, Tag<A, B...> const&) noexcept {
    return (os << '{' << pretty<A, B...>() << '}', os);
    /*auto d = "{";
    ((os << d << pretty<A>(), d=", "),...,(os << d << pretty<B>()));
    return os << '}', os;*/
}

}

#endif
```

Then in tag.cpp

```
#include "utility.hpp"
#include "tag.hpp"


int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    using A=int;
    using B=char;
    X::Tag<> w = {};
    X::Tag<A> x {};
    X::Tag<A,B> y {};
    X::Tag<B> z {};
    // ...
    auto m = y-w;
    auto m2 = y-z;
    // ...
    static_assert(X::Same_v<X::Tag<A, B>, Dt(m)>);
    static_assert(X::Same_v<X::Tag<A>, Dt(m2)>);
}
```

Is my reasoning incorrect? It has all the information it needs to deduce the template arguments, and I would swear I've done this before.

Comment: No, this has never been possible. Only one pack (the right-most) per template argument list in the function parameter type can be deduced and each parameter/argument pair is deduced from independently (and deduction fails if the deduced template arguments don't match).

Comment: For what you are trying to do here write a constexpr `bool`-returning function that compares to `Tag<A...>` and `Tag<B...>`'s types via `std::is_same` the way you need it and then use a `requires` clause on the `operator-` to constrain the types of the two function parameters accordingly.

Comment: @user17732522 I don't see why it can't use the argument list from the rhs object and deduce the earlier arguments in the list. If this is the case, does it mean I could write an alternative that extracts arguments from the other side? That way the remainder it needs to deduce would be trailing.

Comment: No, the rules for template argument deduction don't allow for what you want. Each argument/parameter pair is always deduced individually. The compiler will not consider any correlation between different parameter/argument pairs. That's just how the language is specified. You need to implement the test for your condition yourself. Template argument deduction can't help you.

Comment: [Something along these lines](https://godbolt.org/z/ovs1TE6se), perhaps.